# Programming Chess Rook Movement

Tags: chess

I am trying to create a board game where all the pieces are able to move the same as a rook in chess. (i.e. Horizontally or vertically as many spaces as they wish)

My board is a simple 2d integer array, with values of 0,1,2 depending on whether the space is empty, has a red piece or a black piece.

My code for the movement so far is shown below, it creates a true or false value if the move is allowed or not:

```java
int[][] board;

public boolean validMove(int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
    if (pieceAt(toRow, toCol) != EMPTY) {
        return false;
    } else if (fromRow - toRow == 0 && fromCol - toCol != 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (fromCol - toCol == 0 && fromRow - toRow != 0) {
        // Trying to add piece collision code
        for (int i = fromRow; i < toRow; i++) {
            if (pieceAt(toCol, i) != EMPTY)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is trying to create collision detection, if another piece is in the way it should not be able to move past it, however with my code currently it can. Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. It's quite naive (and also not tested), but I think it should work just as is. And also I think it illustrates the idea pretty well (see comments). It's in C, but I'm sure you can transform it easily to Java (or whatever language you use).

```c
bool validMove(int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol)
{
    int i;

    // Attempt to move to the same cell
    if (fromRow == toRow && fromCol == toCol)
        return false;

    // Collision detection
    if (fromRow == toRow) {
        // Horizontal move
        if (fromCol < toCol) {
            // Move right
            for (i = fromCol + 1; i <= toCol; ++i)
                if (pieceAt(fromRow, i) != EMPTY)
                    return false;
        } else {
            // Move left
            for (i = fromCol - 1; i >= toCol; --i)
                if (pieceAt(fromRow, i) != EMPTY)
                    return false;
        }
    } else if (fromCol == toCol) {
        // Vertical move
        if (fromRow < toRow) {
            // Move down
            for (i = fromRow + 1; i <= toRow; ++i)
                if (pieceAt(i, fromCol) != EMPTY)
                    return false;
        } else {
            // Move up
            for (i = fromRow - 1; i >= toRow; --i)
                if (pieceAt(i, fromCol) != EMPTY)
                    return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not a valid rook move (neither horizontal nor vertical)
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also optimize your code by reducing [conditional statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28computer_programming%29) count, using the method proposed by [Toon Krijthe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18061/toon-krijthe). The main idea is to use "delta" values (`dx`/`dy`) for incrementing or decrementing cell indexes. In that case the destination cell should be checked explicitly.

Code:

```c
bool validMove(int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol)
{
    int i;

    // Attempt to move to the same cell
    if (fromRow == toRow && fromCol == toCol)
        return false;

    // Collision detection
    if (fromRow == toRow) { // Horizontal move
        int dx = (fromCol < toCol) ? 1 : -1;

        for (i = fromCol + dx; i != toCol; i += dx)
            if (pieceAt(fromRow, i) != EMPTY)
                return false;
    } else if (fromCol == toCol) { // Vertical move
        int dy = (fromRow < toRow) ? 1 : -1;

        for (i = fromRow + dy; i != toRow; i += dy)
            if (pieceAt(i, fromCol) != EMPTY)
                return false;
    } else { // Not a valid rook move
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if destination cell is free
    return pieceAt(toRow, toCell) == EMPTY;
}
```

Comment: Can you somehow make the second one do the "check if the destination cell is free" without a separate if statement? That would be even cooler.

Comment: @tomashauser Well, one way to do that would be `return pieceAt(toRow, to Cell) == EMPTY;` in the end of the function, instead of just `return true;`. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

you could have a 2D char array with each cell representing the position on the board. there you can have a char for the three states of the position (white/red/empty).

The other way i can think of is before each move to check from the startPosition till the endPosition positions their states. but performance wise i think the some kind of array will be much better

Answer (score 0):

You can simply "walk" each field in order to check if it is empty.
For example:

```
int[][] board;

public boolean validMove(int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) 
{
  if (pieceAt(toRow, toCol) != EMPTY) return false;
  else if (fromRow == toRow) 
  {
    // horizontal move
    if (fromCol == toCol) return false; // same position
    int dx, x;
    if (fromCol < toCol) 
      dx = 1;
    else 
      dx = -1; 

    for (x = fromCol + dx; x != toCol; x += dx) 
    {
      if (pieceAt(toRow, x) != EMPTY) return false; // occupied
    }
  }
  else if (fromCol == toCol) 
  {
    // vertical move
    int dy, y;
    if (fromRow < toRow) 
      dy = 1;
    else 
      dy = -1; 

    for (y = fromRow + dy; y != toRow; y += dy) 
    {
      if (pieceAt(y, toCol) != EMPTY) return false; // occupied

      return true; // free path
    }
  }
  else return false; // no horizontal or vertical move
```

}

Comment: In your `for` loops' conditions: I think you should replace `x != (toCol-dx)` with `x != toCol`. The same stands for the second loop. `!=` already eliminates checking for destination cell. Doing stuff like `x != (toCol-dx)` is a bug: it will skip one cell from checking.

Comment: It's not clear if you can take any piece. Besides the question was how to detect if there are pieces in between so I skipped the destination cell.

Comment: Doing `x != (toCol-dx)` you are skipping not only the destination cell, but also cell next to it. To skip destination cell you should do `x != toCol`. For example, this code: `for (i = 1; i != 5 - 1; i++)` will only check 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements. Also, you have not skipped the destination cell, it's being checked by this line in your code: `if (pieceAt(toRow, toCol) != EMPTY) return false;`